# error in adding library project to android application

Tags: android

For android app build path adding facebook library project,But it is not highlighting here placing the screenshot.Please look on project selection window.Facebook is not showing .help me thanks in advance.
[image: screen shot]

Comment: Have you put Facebook sdk in same Workspace as project???

Comment: did u marked facebook project as lib?

Comment: Is the properties of the library, is it check as "Is Library"?

Comment: @Anil Bhatiya u r right my FB sdk in workspace ,that causes the problem now problem resolved

Comment: @AnilBhatiya could u make u r comment as answer then i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put Facebook sdk in same Workspace as project...That's it..

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Facebook app(in Eclipse) **go to property >> Android >> select** isLibrary option. refresh both project, try again .

Answer (score 0):

> Mark facebook as library then only it will show

[image]